# angularjs modal - keep changes after close

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog

I have html file

```
<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3>I'm a modal!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                <a ng-click="selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        Selected: <b>{{ selected.item }}</b>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</script>

<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
<div ng-show="selected">Selection from a modal: {{ selected }}</div>
```

and js

```
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

$scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

$scope.open = function () {

var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
  resolve: {
    items: function () {
      return $scope.items;
    }
  }
});

modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
  $scope.selected = selectedItem;
}, function () {
  $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
});
};
};

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

$scope.items = items;
$scope.selected = {
  item: $scope.items[0]
};

$scope.ok = function () {
  $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
};

$scope.cancel = function () {
  $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};
};
```

How to keep changes when I click cancel button and reopen window. 
Link to example http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Comment: like you select item 2 but click cancel and open modal again and item 2 selected again?

Comment: I'm not sure why you want this though, but answered it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works? You can pass items through the $modalInstance.close();

(Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Lbwz5K3Wg8ivp9tBK7Bb?p=preview)

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

  $scope.open = function () {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        },
        selectedItem : function() {
          return $scope.selected;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };
};

// Please note that $modalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $modal service used above.

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, items,selectedItem) {

  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.selected = {
    item: selectedItem || $scope.items[0]
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss($scope.selected.item);
  };
};
```